# jqgrid Error : Object does not support Property or Method 'Split'

Tags: forms, jqgrid, edit

I am using JQGrid v4.4.1 and MVC3.

When Selecting the 'Next Record' or 'Previous Record' icon on The JQGrid Edit Form, I get a Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property of method 'split'.

If highlights a block of code in the jquery.jqgrid.min.js module : **var j=g.split(",")**

Sometimes intellesense says that g=0, other times it's -2: I guess it's data related, but i cannot see anything that could be causing this! 
I've tried to include a section of this module, including this call, but I'm struggling to make head nor tailof it!

Can anyone help me in determining the cause of this error?

**jquery.jqGrid.min.js Extract**

```
2*k+"'>"+t.rowcontent+"</td></tr>"),a(h).append(r),r[0].rp=u);0===m.length&&(m=a("<tr "+q+" rowpos='"+u+"'></tr>").addClass("FormData").attr("id","tr_"+f),a(m).append(p),a(h).append(m),m[0].rp=u);a("td:eq("+(y-2)+")",m[0]).html("undefined"===typeof t.label?e.p.colNames[o]:t.label);a("td:eq("+(y-1)+")",m[0]).append(t.elmprefix).append(l).append(t.elmsuffix);n[j]=o;j++}});if(0<j&&(o=a("<tr class='FormData' style='display:none'><td class='CaptionTD'></td><td colspan='"+(2*k-1)+"' class='DataTD'><input class='FormElement' id='id_g' type='text' name='"+
e.p.id+"_id' value='"+d+"'/></td></tr>"),o[0].rp=j+999,a(h).append(o),c[b.p.id].checkOnSubmit||c[b.p.id].checkOnUpdate))c[b.p.id]._savedData[e.p.id+"_id"]=d;return n}function r(d,e,h){var f,k=0,g,m,j,q,l;if(c[b.p.id].checkOnSubmit||c[b.p.id].checkOnUpdate)c[b.p.id]._savedData={},c[b.p.id]._savedData[e.p.id+"_id"]=d;var o=e.p.colModel;if("_empty"==d)a(o).each(function(){f=this.name;j=a.extend({},this.editoptions||{});if((m=a("#"+a.jgrid.jqID(f),"#"+h))&&m.length&&null!==m[0])if(q="",j.defaultValue?
(q=a.isFunction(j.defaultValue)?j.defaultValue.call(b):j.defaultValue,"checkbox"==m[0].type?(l=q.toLowerCase(),0>l.search(/(false|0|no|off|undefined)/i)&&""!==l?(m[0].checked=!0,m[0].defaultChecked=!0,m[0].value=q):(m[0].checked=!1,m[0].defaultChecked=!1)):m.val(q)):"checkbox"==m[0].type?(m[0].checked=!1,m[0].defaultChecked=!1,q=a(m).attr("offval")):m[0].type&&"select"==m[0].type.substr(0,6)?m[0].selectedIndex=0:m.val(q),!0===c[b.p.id].checkOnSubmit||c[b.p.id].checkOnUpdate)c[b.p.id]._savedData[f]=
q}),a("#id_g","#"+h).val(d);else{var n=a(e).jqGrid("getInd",d,!0);n&&(a('td[role="gridcell"]',n).each(function(m){f=o[m].name;if("cb"!==f&&"subgrid"!==f&&"rn"!==f&&!0===o[m].editable){if(f==e.p.ExpandColumn&&!0===e.p.treeGrid)g=a(this).text();else try{g=a.unformat.call(e,a(this),{rowId:d,colModel:o[m]},m)}catch(i){g="textarea"==o[m].edittype?a(this).text():a(this).html()}b.p.autoencode&&(g=a.jgrid.htmlDecode(g));if(!0===c[b.p.id].checkOnSubmit||c[b.p.id].checkOnUpdate)c[b.p.id]._savedData[f]=g;f=
a.jgrid.jqID(f);switch(o[m].edittype){case "password":case "text":case "button":case "image":case "textarea":if("&nbsp;"==g||"&#160;"==g||1==g.length&&160==g.charCodeAt(0))g="";a("#"+f,"#"+h).val(g);break;case "select":var j=g.split(","),j=a.map(j,function(b){return a.trim(b)});a("#"+f+" option","#"+h).each(function(){this.selected=!o[m].editoptions.multiple&&(a.trim(g)==a.trim(a(this).text())||j[0]==a.trim(a(this).text())||j[0]==a.trim(a(this).val()))?!0:o[m].editoptions.multiple?-1<a.inArray(a.trim(a(this).text()),
j)||-1<a.inArray(a.trim(a(this).val()),j)?!0:!1:!1});break;case "checkbox":g+="";o[m].editoptions&&o[m].editoptions.value?o[m].editoptions.value.split(":")[0]==g?(a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("checked",!0),a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("defaultChecked",!0)):(a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("checked",!1),a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("defaultChecked",!1)):(g=g.toLowerCase(),0>g.search(/(false|0|no|off|undefined)/i)&&""!==g?(a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?
"prop":"attr"]("checked",!0),a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("defaultChecked",!0)):(a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("checked",!1),a("#"+f,"#"+h)[b.p.useProp?"prop":"attr"]("defaultChecked",!1)));break;case "custom":try{if(o[m].editoptions&&a.isFunction(o[m].editoptions.custom_value))o[m].editoptions.custom_value.call(b,a("#"+f,"#"+h),"set",g);else throw"e1";}catch(q){"e1"==q?a.jgrid.info_dialog(jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap,"function 'custom_value' "+a.jgrid.edit.msg.nodefined,jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose):
a.jgrid.info_dialog(jQuery.jgrid.errors.errcap,q.message,jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose)}}k++}}),0<k&&a("#id_g",i).val(d))}}function u(){a.each(b.p.colModel,function(a,b){b.editoptions&&!0===b.editoptions.NullIfEmpty&&k.hasOwnProperty(b.name)&&""===k[b.name]&&(k[b.name]="null")})}function t(){var e,f=[!0,"",""],m={},g=b.p.prmNames,j,o,l,n,v,p=a(b).triggerHandler("jqGridAddEditBeforeCheckValues",[a("#"+h),z]);p&&"object"===typeof p&&(k=p);a.isFunction(c[b.p.id].beforeCheckValues)&&(p=c[b.p.id].beforeCheckValues.call(b,
k,a("#"+h),"_empty"==k[b.p.id+"_id"]?g.addoper:g.editoper))&&"object"===typeof p&&(k=p);for(l in k)if(k.hasOwnProperty(l)&&(f=a.jgrid.checkValues.call(b,k[l],l,b),!1===f[0]))break;u();f[0]&&(m=a(b).triggerHandler("jqGridAddEditClickSubmit",[c[b.p.id],k,z]),void 0===m&&a.isFunction(c[b.p.id].onclickSubmit)&&(m=c[b.p.id].onclickSubmit.call(b,c[b.p.id],k)||{}),f=a(b).triggerHandler("jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit",[k,a("#"+h),z]),void 0===f&&(f=[!0,"",""]),f[0]&&a.isFunction(c[b.p.id].beforeSubmit)&&(f=c[b.p.id].beforeSubmit.call(b,
k,a("#"+h))));if(f[0]&&!c[b.p.id].processing){c[b.p.id].processing=!0;a("#sData",i+"_2").addClass("ui-state-active");o=g.oper;j=g.id;k[o]="_empty"==a.trim(k[b.p.id+"_id"])?g.addoper:g.editoper;k[o]!=g.addoper?k[j]=k[b.p.id+"_id"]:void 0===k[j]&&(k[j]=k[b.p.id+"_id"]);delete k[b.p.id+"_id"];k=a.extend(k,c[b.p.id].editData,m);if(!0===b.p.treeGrid)for(v in k[o]==g.addoper&&(n=a(b).jqGrid("getGridParam","selrow"),k["adjacency"==b.p.treeGridModel?b.p.treeReader.parent_id_field:"parent_id"]=n),b.p.treeReader)b.p.treeReader.hasOwnProperty(v)&&
(m=b.p.treeReader[v],k.hasOwnProperty(m)&&!(k[o]==g.addoper&&"parent_id_
```

Comment: you should replace `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and repeat the test. You should post the line number from `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` where the error take place.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks A lot for this gem :)  I am now using jquery.jqgrid.src.js and it gave me enough info to pouint me in the direction of a column that was using a formatter - which was the cause of the issue. I'll post the solution below. Thanks again. Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Oleg pointed me in the right direction (thanks Oleg!). I have managed to resolve this Error.

Using The **jquery.jqgrid.src.js** (much more readable) I managed to take an educated guess that the problem lay on a column in my Grid that was using a FORMATTER. I then noticed that even when loading the Edit form - the value for this column was not correct - and bacause The edittype was 'select', it was defaulting to the first item in the value list.

The Formatter would take the Value of the column (which could be either a -2, 0 or 1 in this case) and turn it into a gif for display purposes in the column. that worked lovely.

The UnFormatter, however, attempted to turn the image back into it's respective number  (based on its title). I was then returning a numeric value ( ie. -2, 0 or 1). **I needed to return a string value. (ie. '-2','0' or '1')**

So, it seems that for Unformatters, you cannot return numeric values like this.

I have added the working code below for clarity :)

**Working formatters**

```
function EnabledFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var cellValueInt = parseInt(cellvalue);
    switch (cellValueInt)
    {
        case 1:
            return "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/tick.gif")' title='Enabled' />";
            break;
        case -2:
            return "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/tick-grey.png")' title='Inherited' />";
            break;
        default:
            return "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/cross.gif")' title='Disabled' />";
            break;
    };
};

function EnabledUnformatter (cellvalue, options, cell) {
    var sTitle = $('img', cell).attr('title');

    switch (sTitle)
    {
        case 'Enabled':
            return '1';
            break;
        case 'Inherited':
            return '-2';
            break;
        default:
            return '0';
            break;
    };
};
```

**Broken Unformatter** Please note The lack of '' around the values returned. The EnabledFormatter is Unchanged

```
function EnabledUnformatter (cellvalue, options, cell) {
    var sTitle = $('img', cell).attr('title');

    switch (sTitle)
    {
        case 'Enabled':
            return 1;
            break;
        case 'Inherited':
            return -2;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    };
};
```